# My Java code doesn't enter to For loop to retrieve ArrayList elements

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

I am trying to retrieve some specific data from `ArrayList` elements using `For loop` in `Java`.

But whenever I run the code it simply skips the loop.

```
    String sel=(String)jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();

    for(int i=0;i<arrTrans.size(); i++){
        if(arrTrans.get(i).date.equals(sel)){
        descView.setText(arrTrans.get(i).description);
        typeView.setText(arrTrans.get(i).type);
        amountView.setText(arrTrans.get(i).amount);
                }
```

During Debug process I tracked `arrTrans.size()` end it is not zero, as I add continuously new `Lists`. I wonder why it's like that?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
for(int i=0;i>arrTrans.size(); i++)
```

to

```
for(int i=0;i<arrTrans.size(); i++)
```

You misunderstood the condition in the middle of the for loop : it does not mean "While my condition **is not** true", it means "While my condition **is** true"

The loop would have never been executed with what you typed. `arrTrans.length` will never give you something inferior to 0, because the `ArrayList`'s length is 0 if it is empty.

EDIT : If it is not a problem with the for-loop condition, it might be a problem with the ArrayList. Try to replace `i<arrTrans.size()` by `i<arrTrans.toArray().length`, it might help

Comment: Yes you are right! I changed it but no chance! Still experiencing the same problem.

Comment: It might be a problem with the `ArrayList`, too. See my edit on my answer. I know that it should be the same output...

Answer (score 5):

You need to change

```
for(int i=0;i>arrTrans.size(); i++){
```

To

```
for(int i=0;i<arrTrans.size(); i++){
```

`arrTrans.size()` is a size of a collection so `arrTrans.size()>=0`. Then `i` start from `0` so your current code will not enter inside for loop since `i>arrTrans.size()` is not matched.

Edit:

Now you have edited your question to `for(int i=0;i<arrTrans.size(); i++)` if you still has the same issue definitely `arrTrans.size()` is `0`

Answer (score 0):

`for(int i=0;i>arrTrans.size(); i++)` ?. surely you meant - `for(int i=0;i<arrTrans.size(); i++)`.  If the size of the `arrTrans` is zero, then it will not enter into the loop.

Comment: The size of an arraylist can be zero.

Comment: @TomJonckheere - My bad, I meant it in a different way. thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 0):

use `less than` in place of `greater than` in conditional part of your for loop
write this `for(int i=0;i<arrTrans.size(); i++){`

write whole code like

```
String sel=(String)jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();

    for(int i=0;i<arrTrans.size(); i++){   //change is needed just here
        if(arrTrans.get(i).date.equals(sel)){
        descView.setText(arrTrans.get(i).description);
        typeView.setText(arrTrans.get(i).type);
        amountView.setText(arrTrans.get(i).amount);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

It skips the loop because of the statement `i>arrTrans.size()`.
i is equal to 0, so for the loop to be evaluated arrTrans.size() must be smaller than 0.
An arraylist cannot have a negative size, thus
the loop is skipped. Change: `i>arrTrans.size()` to `i<arrTrans.size()` to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not skipping for if you have some any elements in Arraylist it may your

//if(arrTrans.get(i).date.equals(sel)){

this condition is not satisfying and it not display any result.